# Objective-C Use NSString in other method

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem and I don't know how to fix it.

Viewcontroller.m

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
NSLog(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/blabla.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"udid=%@&submit=",deviceTokenString];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I want the deviceTokenString from application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken to viewDidLoad in the post but it won't work.

When I have this code in ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
NSString *deviceTokenString;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *deviceTokenString;
```

it only returns "Null" and not the deviceToken

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with two different classes, your UIApplication's delegate class and a UIViewController class. Instance variables defined in one class are not exposed to other classes by default, unless they are also defined as properties of the class.

In your case, you've defined a property on the View Controller class for your `deviceTokenString` object. So, you've exposed this property of the View Controller to other classes that might be interested in accessing this object.

Inside your UIApplicationDelegate object, in the `didReceiveRemote...` method, a NSString object is passed in for you by the system with the parameter name `deviceToken`. When you receive this object, you don't need to do any other operations on it (ie `stringWithFormat:`).

What you might or might not encounter in your app is something called a race condition. `viewDidLoad` might happen before your app receives the `didReceiveToken` message. Be wary of this.

To solve your problem, what you should do is access your viewController object in the `didReceiveRemote...` method, like so:

```
-(void)didReceiveToken... {
      UIViewController *myViewController = self.viewController; //how do you initially set up this object?
      myViewController.deviceTokenString = deviceToken;
}
```

Not saying that this is the best way to do it, but it will solve your problem. Also leaves other things out, like what happens when you set the property. Doing it in viewDidLoad is an easy way to do things automatically. A way around this is to use Key-Value-Observing, which is another question/tutorial in itself.

GOod luck.

Answer (score 1):

> it only returns "Null" and not the deviceToken

That's because you've declared a local variable with the same name as your instance variable. In `-application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` you've got:

```
NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
```

which creates a local variable named `deviceTokenString`. That variable goes away as soon as the method exits. You never set the instance variable, so when you try to access that in `-viewDidLoad` you get nil.

To fix the problem, simply change the line above to:

```
deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
```

Now you're using the `deviceTokenString` that is your instance variable, so the value will be assigned to the ivar and will persist beyond the end of the method.

Comment: @HenkdeBoer Sorry -- I wrote a little too quickly. See Justin's explanation also; he's right that you are (or should be) talking about two different classes. `-application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is an application delegate method, while `-viewDidLoad` is a view controller method. A single object doesn't normally function as both app delegate and view controller. So, you'll probably want to have the app delegate send the view controller a message with the string or (not quite as good) have the view controller ask the app delegate for the string.

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring the NSString deviceTokenString in the -(void)application function. That local declaration supersedes the property declared in the interface. So when that application function goes out of scope, the NSString object you created (which is on the stack) is no longer existent.

Remove the NSString * from the -(void)application function

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application    
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

      NSLog(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
      deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
}
```

This should fix your issue

Comment: The synthesis won’t be necessary with any recent version of the iOS SDK.